# mongo shell command not accept use db command

Tags: mongodb

i am trying to pull records form mongo data base with json format to do that i am running below js :

```
conatin of get_DRMPhysicalresources_Data.js
    cursor = db.physicalresources.find().limit(10)
    while ( cursor.hasNext() ){
       print( JSON.stringify(cursor.next()) );
    }

the command i run to get the records : 
    mongo host_name:port/data_base_name -u user -p 'password' --eval "load(\"get_DRMPhysicalresources_Data.js\")" > DRMPhysicalresources.json
```

and i am able to get the result as josn formate inside DRMPhysicalresources.json , now i want to switch to other data base using use command i try add use db as below :

```
 conatin of get_DRMPhysicalresources_Data.js
    use db2_test
    cursor = db.physicalresources.find().limit(10)
    while ( cursor.hasNext() ){
       print( JSON.stringify(cursor.next()) );
    }
    the command i run to get the records : 
    mongo host_name:port/data_base_name -u user -p 'password' --eval "load(\"get_DRMPhysicalresources_Data.js\")" > DRMPhysicalresources.json
```

but i am getting below errors :

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: "some data base info"
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("8c85c6af-ebed-416d-9ab8-d6739a4230cb") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.11
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
2022-04-11T13:39:30.121+0300 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell eval):1:1
2022-04-11T13:39:30.122+0300 E  QUERY    [js] Error: error loading js file: get_DRMPhysicalresources_Data.js :
@(shell eval):1:1
2022-04-11T13:39:30.122+0300 E  -        [main] exiting with code -4
```

is there are any way to add use db2_test without break it ?

Comment: Try `db.getSiblingDB('db2_test').physicalresources.find()` or `mongo host_name:port/db2_test -u user -p 'password' ...` - however, your code should actually work. Maybe pay attention to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 db = new Mongo().getDB("myOtherDatabase");
```

or

```
 db = db.getSiblingDB('myOtherDatabase')
```

( this is the exact js equivalent to the 'use database' helper)

[docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Comment: thanks db = db.getSiblingDB('myOtherDatabase') work for me